# Maxwell's Inspiration to think about fields

Tags: statistical-mechanics, history, field-theory

I was looking at a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Historical_significance) which had the following statement

> *Atomists, notably James Clerk Maxwell and Ludwig Boltzmann, applied [...].*

In modern literature Maxwell is often thought of as a field theorist. Is anyone aware of exactly how the switch from thinking "atomistically" to a more field theoretic view happened. I have been told it was experiment but I have read some texts in the past that show mathematical derivations.
    I think I am interested in knowing exactly what theoretical and mathematical foresight led Maxwell to make such a radical change.

Comment: Note there is a new [History of Science and Math](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) site that this sort of question would probably do well on.

Comment: @ChrisWhite This question would be *perfect* for HSM.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's thermodynamics and E&M were both atomistic.

For example, in his *Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism* §255, he found it

> extremely natural to suppose that the currents of the ions are convection currents of electricity, and, in particular, that every molecule of the cation is charged with a certain fixed quantity of positive electricity, which is the same for the molecules of all cations, and that every molecule of the anion is charged with an equal quantity of negative electricity.

Comment: I think this answer takes that one sentence of the question too literally? Yes there are atoms, but there are also fields with a reality/effect of their own, and that's a big switch from saying that there are atoms with some instantaneous action at a distance force.